# libev custom events

Tags: c++, asynchronous, libev

I am trying to use libev for event based programming. But there are some events provided by libev like `EV_READ, EV_WRITE, EV_TIMER ..`

So, is it possible to have an custom event of my own.

For instance, I have a continuous flow of messages from a socket an I am interested in only a type of message in that stream of messages. So, its basically like

```
while(true)
{
     Msg msg = getMessage();
     if(msg != null && msg.id == ourId)
         return msg;
}
```

So, I want to register for events of this sort (only that `if` condition is satisfied.) . Its a custom event right ? How do I specify this event to libev.

I mean in libev we specify like this ..

```
ev_io_init (&stdin_watcher, stdin_cb, /*STDIN_FILENO*/ 0, EV_READ);
ev_io_start (loop, &stdin_watcher);
```

I dint see any stuff where we can check for our own events. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot have a custom event, because libev doesn't manipulate with your data, just checks if there are some, or if you can send some.

So basically, you will have to:

1. Create a watcher with `EV_READ`
2. When the watcher fires your function, check if there is a message you want:

   - if yes, push it to your message queue
   - if not, just skip it
3. Run `ev_loop`, ideally with `EV_ONESHOT` and a timeout watcher. Right after that call your message handler, which will check the message queue and process all messages thet are in the queue